# Why doesn't this d3 component work when the input type changes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm following along with [this tutorial for React and d3](https://github.com/freddyrangel/playing-with-react-and-d3), and now I'm trying to play with the schema the state follows.

I'm changing a function that supplies the initial state from

```
var randomData = [];
d3.range(settings.numDataPoints).forEach(function() {
      var newNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.maxRange());
      var newNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.maxRange());
      randomData.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]);
    });
```

to

```
var randomData = d3.range(settings.numDataPoints).map(function(thisPoint) {
      var newNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.maxRange());
      var newNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.maxRange());
      return {ind: thisPoint, coords: [newNumber1, newNumber2]};
    });
```

As a result, I have to also change the DataCircles `renderCircles()` function from

```
  renderCircles: function(coords) {
    var props = {
      cx: this.props.xScale(coords[0]),
      cy: this.props.yScale(coords[1]),
      r: 2,
      key: uuid.v4()
    };
    return (
      <circle {...props}>
      </circle>
    );
  }
```

to

```
  renderCircles: function(coordsObj) {
    var props = {
      cx: this.props.xScale(coordsObj.coords[0]),
      cy: this.props.yScale(coordsObj.coords[1]),
      r: 2,
      key: uuid.v4()
    };
    return (
      <circle {...props}>
      </circle>
    );
  }
```

This causes all of the previously nicely-rendered dots on the XY grid created in the tutorial to disappear, leaving only a blank graph:

[image: blank graph]

I've logged the objects in both function scopes and verified that the data is being produced properly. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the structure of randomData, I think you missed that it is also a prop for the `<ScatterPlot />` component, so you need to update that as well:

```
getXScale: function(props) {
  var xMax = d3.max(props.data, function(d) { return d.coords[0] });
  return d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([props.padding, props.width - props.padding * 2]);
},

getYScale: function(props) {
  var yMax = d3.max(props.data, function(d) { return d.coords[1] });
  return d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([props.height - props.padding, props.padding]);
},
```

Comment: Exactly right! Seems this tutorial couples its components pretty strongly, at least, around data.